# Print the selected parameters in nested cross-validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Below is an example of using scikit-learn to get cross-validated predictions from *k*-nearest neighbors, with *k* chosen by cross-validation. The code seems to work, but how can I also print the *k* that was selected in each of the outer folds?

```
import numpy as np, sklearn

n = 100
X = np.random.randn(n, 2)
y = np.where(np.sum(X, axis = 1) + np.random.randn(n) > 0, "blue", "red")

preds = sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict(
    X = X,
    y = y,
    estimator = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(
       estimator = sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(),
       param_grid = {'n_neighbors': range(1, 7)},
       cv = sklearn.model_selection.KFold(10, random_state = 133),
       scoring = 'accuracy'),
    cv = sklearn.model_selection.KFold(10, random_state = 144))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get this directly from that function, so you would need to replace `cross_val_predict` with `cross_validate` and set the `return_estimator` flag to `True`. You can then select the estimators used in the returned dictionary with the key `estimator`. The selected parameters of the estimators is stored in the attribute `best_params_`. So

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
# sklearn 0.20.3 doesn't seem to import submodules in __init__
# So importing them directly is required.
import sklearn.model_selection
import sklearn.neighbors

n = 100
X = np.random.randn(n, 2)
y = np.where(np.sum(X, axis = 1) + np.random.randn(n) > 0, "blue", "red")

scores = sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate(
    X = X,
    y = y,
    estimator = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(
       estimator = sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(),
       param_grid = {'n_neighbors': range(1, 7)},
       cv = sklearn.model_selection.KFold(10, random_state = 133),
       scoring = 'accuracy'),
    cv = sklearn.model_selection.KFold(10, random_state = 144),
    return_estimator=True)

# Selected hyper-parameters for the estimator from the first fold
print(scores['estimator'][0].best_params_)
```

Unfortunately you can't get the actual predictions AND the hyper-parameters selected from the same function. If you want that, you will have to do the nested cross-validation manually:

```
cv = sklearn.model_selection.KFold(10, random_state = 144)
estimator = sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV(
       estimator = sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(),
       param_grid = {'n_neighbors': range(1, 7)},
       cv = sklearn.model_selection.KFold(10, random_state = 133),
       scoring = 'accuracy')
for train, test in cv.split(X,y):
    X_train, y_train = X[train], y[train]
    X_test, y_test = X[test], y[test]
    m = estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)
    print(m.best_params_)
    y_pred = m.predict(X_test)
    print(y_pred)
```

Comment: Any idea, then, how I can get predictions and the parameters selected without running the model extra times?